# Pidgin GUI uses "dark theme": not usable

Tags: gnome, themes, colors, pidgin

Since I installed Gnome pidgin is using a color palette that is not readable. It uses dark text over dark background or light color text over light color background.

In Gnome, in general, the "dark theme" is a whole mess, so I deactivated it, but in pidgin it still is rendering with the wrong colors.

[Screenshot with a Pidgin window that can't be read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4qth.png)